# How do I import data from a csv when the records are not separated by line breaks but with brackets

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv

Looking at the AM data, just for a data analysis project and I'm having trouble importing the data into my dbms (postgresql).

My code is sql code is this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS member_details;
CREATE TABLE member_details(
  pnum varchar(255),
  .....
  updatedon timestamp);
COPY member_details
FROM '/Users/etc/data/sample_dump.csv'
WITH DELIMITER ','
CSV;
```

Problem is that the csv file has no line breaks to separate the data, instead each record is within a bracket which my code above does not recognise and thus just imports all the data into the header in one line and so no records are created

how the data is structured
(dataA1, ....,dataAx),(dataB1,...,dataBx)

How can I alter my code so that postgresql imports the data record by record by recognising the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the PostgreSQL `COPY` [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html), I don't believe it allows for row delimiters other than carriage returns and/or line feeds.  I believe you'll need to process your file before importing. You can simply replace all `,(` with `\n(`, then replace all the parenthesis to make it a standard csv format that `COPY` will happy consume.

Perhaps there's another method for PostgreSQL that would work too, but I haven't come across anything yet.